# Is it possible to make a elipse on folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

i saw on the internet images that folium generate a elipse form on map, is it possible, i tried creating manually but is inviable point per point, is there any way to do that ?
[elipse on folium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osKxk.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using folium's Polygon (and some other stuff)

I copied this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45254501/3437504) for the polygon construction

```
import math
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.affinity import scale, rotate

#input parameters
A = Point(-95.5, 41.25)
B = Point(-96.5, 41.25)
R = .25

d = A.distance(B)

#first, rotate B to B' around A so that |AB'| = |AB| and B'.y = A.y
#and then take S as midpoint of AB'
S = Point(A.x + d/2, A.y)

#alpha represents the angle of this rotation
alpha = math.atan2(B.y - A.y, B.x - A.x)

#create a circle with center at S passing through A and B'
C = S.buffer(d/2)

#rescale this circle in y-direction so that the corresponding
#axis is R units long
C = scale(C, 1, R/(d/2))

#rotate the ellipse obtained in previous step around A into the
#original position (positive angles represent counter-clockwise rotation)
C = rotate(C, alpha, origin = A, use_radians = True)
```

Where C is a shapely polygon

```
print(type(C))
<class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
```

I flip the coordinates from X,Y to Y,X to make it folium friendly

`folium_poly = [[y,x] for x,y in C.exterior.coords]`

then folium for the rest

```
import folium

m = folium.Map([C.centroid.y, C.centroid.x])
folium.Polygon(folium_poly).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]